# how to include 5 <BR>'s in Haml?

Tags: ruby, haml

this code

```
= 5.times {|n| puts "<BR>"}
```

does nothing for me ...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
- 5.times do
  %br
```

Comment: I still wouldn't use br tags.

Comment: Why @JeremyWeiskotten? What else do you recommend using?

Answer (score 10):

Another way:

```
= "<br/>"*5
```

Comment: I like yours better ;-) Thank you for that

Answer (score 2):

You can use % to specifically add a tag.  So, for 5 
 do

```
%br/
%br/
%br/
%br/
%br/
```

But: why would you want to do this?  It would probably be a better idea to use a %div
and set the spacing in CSS rather than multiple BR tags.

Comment: I agree with Joshua. Don't use BR tags.

Comment: I just needed to divide some text during my debugging and also I was sure I can do it easily in ruby but didn't figure out how..

Answer (score 1):

You can also insert regular html.

Like this:

```
%p
  Headline
  <br><br><br><br><br>
  Paragraph goes here, blah blah blah...
```

Or like that:

```
:plain
  <br><br><br><br><br>
```